# Casting a specific hour and minute and getting the time difference

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have the following:

```
trunc(sysdate - to_timestamp(trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 12:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH245:MI')  * 1440,1)
```

What I'm trying to do is, using the date portion of sysdate and casting 12:30 to the time part. Then calculating the difference between sysdate@12:30 and the current sysdate.

I'm getting:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got TIMESTAMP
```

after the minus sign.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're trying to multiply a timestamp by 1440, rather than the difference between the date and timestamp - [multiplication has higher precedence than subtraction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/About-SQL-Operators.html#GUID-FEF44762-F45C-41D9-B380-F6A61AD25338). You also have `HH245` instead of `HH24` in your format model; `trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` will throw "ORA-01898: too many precision specifiers"; and if you changed that to `to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ...` you would be subtracting a timestamp from a date [which gives you an interval](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705), not a number, and would throw a different ORA-00932 error.

Fixing all of those issues, you would end up with:

```
trunc((sysdate - to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 12:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')) * 1440, 1)
```

which would evaluate to 354.2 for me at the moment.

You don't need to convert to or from string though. You can get 12:30 today with:

```
trunc(sysdate) + (12.5/24)
```

where `trunc(sysdate)` gives you midnight today, and 12.5/24 gives you the fraction of a day for 12.5 hours. You can then subtract that from the current time:

```
sysdate - (trunc(sysdate) + (12.5/24))
```

to get the difference in days, then multiple that result by 1440 for the number of minutes, and truncate to a single decimal place.

Quick demo with current date and 12:30 today plus the difference three ways:

```
select sysdate,
  trunc(sysdate) + (12.5/24) as "12:30",
  sysdate - (trunc(sysdate) + (12.5/24)) as diff_days,
  (sysdate - (trunc(sysdate) + (12.5/24))) * 1440 as diff_mins,
  trunc((sysdate - (trunc(sysdate) + (12.5/24))) * 1440, 1) as result
from dual;

SYSDATE             12:30                DIFF_DAYS  DIFF_MINS     RESULT
------------------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2019-08-14 18:24:16 2019-08-14 12:30:00 .246018519 354.266667      354.2
```

---

As @GordonLinoff hinted, the today-at-12:30 part could be achieved with an interval instead of a fractional day, e.g.:

```
trunc(sysdate) + 12.5 * interval '1' hour
```

or more simply and explicitly:

```
trunc(sysdate) + interval '12:30' hour to minute
```

You seem to want your final result as the number of minutes, but you could also get it as an interval, either by converting the current number-of-days intermediate result (or number of minutes) with `numtodsinterval()`:

```
numtodsinterval(sysdate - (trunc(sysdate) + interval '12:30' hour to minute), 'DAY')
```

which is a bit convoluted, or directly:

```
select systimestamp,
  systimestamp - trunc(sysdate) - interval '12:30' hour to minute as result
from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP                         RESULT             
------------------------------------ -------------------
2019-08-14 18:24:16.830116000 +01:00 +00 05:54:16.830116
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d4e27c5892626aeb56c607689fb0f58a)

Comment: Brilliant Thank you very much.

Comment: @AlexPoole . . . This is a very good answer, but you have missed an opportunity to introduce `interval`.